# Textarea using Bootstrap too wide and not aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, textarea

I just started with Bootstrap and having an issue with textarea HTML element - it doesn't follow left alignment with other text fields and goes across the entire page instead.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div id="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">
                    Name
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">
                    E-mail
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="comment">
                    Message
                </label>
                <div class="cols-sm-4">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result looks like this below.

**Textarea too wide and not aligning with other text elements above it**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fix this:

```
            <div class="cols-sm-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
```

to

```
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You could add:

```
.cols-sm-4{
width: 33.33333333%;
margin-left: 15px;
display: inline-block;
}
```